# Почему .h-файл не видит импортируемые в него типы данных?

Tags: c++

Есть .h-файл, с таким исходным кодом:

```
#pragma once

#include <Windows.h>

typedef struct _PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION32
{
    NTSTATUS    ExitStatus;
    ULONG       PebBaseAddress;
    ULONG       AffinityMask;
    DWORD   BasePriority;
    ULONG       uUniqueProcessId;
    ULONG       uInheritedFromUniqueProcessId;
} PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION32, *PPROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION32;
```

Этот файл взят с другого проекта, который успешно компилируется. После добавления данного файла в новый проект - Intellisense начал писать `identifier 'NTSTATUS' is undefined`. При попытке скомпилировать модуль возникает `Error C3646   'ExitStatus': unknown override specifier` и ещё куча ошибок, связанных с этим. При переходе в .cpp-файл (в `#include` которого только соответственный .h), Intellisense уже показывает, что `NTSTATUS` - это `typedef _Return_type_success_(return >= 0) LONG NTSTATUS` с файла `bcrypt.h`. Вопрос остаётся прежним: почему .h-файл не видит импортируемые в него типы данных? (хотя в старом проекте при таком же исходном коде он всё видит)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

проверьте, виден ли файл bcrypt.h в файлах заголовков проекта
и попробуйте добавить

```
#include "bcrypt.h"
```

в h-файл, который не видит импортируемые в него типы данных